# Laravel: skip via database notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I am trying to send the explicit via `Email` only using the notification class where it is configured for both `['mail', 'database']`

`Notification::route('mail', $shopadmin->email)->notify(new ShopadminCreated($model));`

But it still goes into `toArray()` method and generates error.

The reason is, I am using the same class to renotify using email but this time no database entry need to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution:

After stumbling upon the Documentation on Notification. I tried [this block](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels) of code and implement with below modification:

**ShopadminCreated.php:**

```
...
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return $notifiable->prefers_email ? ['mail'] : ['mail', 'database']; 
    //return ['mail', 'database'];
}
...
```

**Controller:**

```
$data = $notification->data; // Array fetched from database
$model = Admin::hydrate([$data])[0];
$model->setAttribute('prefers_email', true);

Notification::send($shopadmin, new ShopadminCreated($model));
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot! Currently I'm using this approach to determine whether we need to send either database or mail notification: `return $notifiable instanceof User ? ['database'] : ['mail'];`.